# Increment of Variable goes wrong

Tags: modelica, dymola

the variable is now starting with j = 1, but the increment is wrong. For t = 0.5 it should have the value of 2 and for t = 1, j = 3 and so on...
You see the error on the following image

[image: variable j]

```
class abc

import Modelica.SIunits;

parameter SIunits.Time delta_t = 0.5;

constant Real a[:] = {4,2,6,-1,3,5,7,4,-3,-6};

Real x;
Integer j(start=1);
Integer k = size(a,1);

algorithm
when {(sample(delta_t, delta_t) and j < k),j == 1} then

     x := a[pre(j)];
     j := pre(j) + 1;

end when;
end abc;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. Dymola can generate plots like this, it depends on the output settings. The plot above was generated without the setting "Store variables at events", when I set this, I get the right result.

Answer (score 0):

When I put your code into Dymola 2013, I get exactly what you expected, `j==2` @ `time==0.5`.

Where does this plot come from?  Dymola does not generate plots like that since `j` is a discrete variables.